# GridLayoutManager in recyclerview with space among elements and matching the full width

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

I want to use a gridlayout manager, the items to be in 2 columns.
I want each row to be evenly split among the items and have some small space around the items too.
I did:

```
val manager = GridLayoutManager(this, 4)
manager.spanSizeLookup = object: GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
     override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int = 2
}
recycler.layoutManager = manager
```

but even though the items in each row are of equal size, they have a huge gap between them and have no space with items bellow.
How can I fix this?
Please note that I used a specific width/size for the inflated items in the view. I guess that is an issue but not sure what should I use for those

Answer (score 1):

1. If you need just two items for column you don't have to set the `spanSizeLookup` property, just set the `layoutManager` and add an `ItemDecoration` for spacing:

```
val manager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2)
recycler.layoutManager = manager  
recycler.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this, manager.orientation)
```

2. Make sure your recycler item layout parent view has its `layout_width` set to `match_parent`

Comment: If I use `layout_margin="8dp"` wont that become 16 dp in the middle? I.e. 8 from each item?

Comment: Actually that adds marging only to the border with the recyclerview

Comment: @Jim That's why you need to set the padding to the recycler view

Comment: Actually I had to add `ItemDecoration` because otherwise the items were not spaced apart

Comment: But the other 2 of your suggestions helped

Comment: If you adapt for that, I can accept the answer

Comment: That's weird. Anyway, I've edited the answer.